# plasticSCM upgrade - Client.conf root element is missing

Tags: plasticscm

I updated PlasticSCM to the latest version (8.0.16). Now when I start plastic I get that error: the client configuration file "client.conf" contains error: Root element is missing.

[image: error box]

Everything worked correctly before updating. I tried reinstalling PlasticSCM and remove client.conf file but it did not help the client still does not start.

Answer (score 0):

The Plastic SCM *client.conf* file is used by both the GUI and the CLI to store the main user preferences.

> I tried reinstalling PlasticSCM and remove client.conf file but it did
>   not help the client still does not start.

It's ok to remove it, but additionally, you need to reconfigure the Plastic SCM Client. Please run the following command to do it.

```
plastic --configure
```

or run the "Client configuration wizard".

[image]

If you keep facing the problem I recommend you to open a support ticket -> https://www.plasticscm.com/support. The team will help you to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for help I wrote to technical support. I have received information that must delete the file from the AppData folder as well. Now the plastic client is working.